# Differentiable bandpass filter?

Tags: audio, pytorch, signals, signal-processing, fft

Does anyone know of any code or implementation of a differentiable bandpass filter, one that is differentiable with respect to frequency?

I am trying to optimize a filterbank and need a filterbank that is differentiable with respect to the central frequency of each filter. Ideally, differentiable with respect to the width as well.

Thanks,
Mason

Comment: Do you mean "adjustable" instead of "differentiable"?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function

Comment: I mean a bandpass filter where we can compute the output signal's derivative with respect to frequency, so that we can use a gradient-based method to optimize it.